# Java Ball Movement: Unexpected Behavior with Boundary Reflections

Tags: java, math, collision-detection, physics, collision

`Question:

I'm working on a Java program where I simulate the movement of a ball within a box. The ball is expected to reflect off the boundaries of the box using the vector reflection formula. However, I'm encountering unexpected behavior where the ball not only goes outside the boundary but also changes its position strangely.

Problem Description:

I have implemented the ball movement using basic line equations (X=x0+at, Y=y0+bt, Z=z0+ct). The part of the code responsible for detecting collisions and updating the ball's path is where I suspect the issue lies.`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get initial positions for ball 1
        System.out.print("Enter ball 1's initial x-coordinate (x): ");
        double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter ball 1's initial y-coordinate (y): ");
        double y1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter ball 1's initial z-coordinate (z): ");
        double z1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter ball 1's radius(r): ");
        double r1 = scanner.nextDouble();

        // Get direction vectorfor ball 1
        System.out.print("Enter direction in x-coordinate (a): ");
        double a = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter direction in y-coordinate (b): ");
        double b = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter direction in z-coordinate (c): ");
        double c = scanner.nextDouble();



        double rt = 0;
        double t1 = 0;
        double t2 = 0;
        while(true) {
            double X1 = x1 + a * t1;
            double Y1 = y1 + b * t1;
            double Z1 = z1 + c * t1;

//**collision**

//This is the part that detects the collision and makes a new path for the ball
            
            if (X1-r1 < -25){
                a = -a;
                x1 = -x1;
                System.out.printf("ball hit\n");

            }
            else if (X1+r1 > 25){
                a = -a;
                x1 = -x1;
                System.out.printf("ball hit\n");
                System.out.printf("%f%f%f\n", a, b, c);
            }
            else if (Y1-r1 < -25){
                b = -b;
                y1 = -y1;
                System.out.printf("ball hit\n");
                System.out.printf("%f%f%f\n", a, b, c);
            }
            else if (Y1+r1 > 25){
                b = -b;
                y1 = -y1;
                System.out.printf("ball hit\n");
                System.out.printf("%f%f%f\n", a, b, c);
            }
            else if (Z1-r1 < -25){
                c = -c;
                z1 = -z1;
                System.out.printf("ball hit\n");
                System.out.printf("%f%f%f\n", a, b, c);
            }
            else if (Z1+r1 > 25){
                c = -c;
                z1 = -z1;
                System.out.printf("ball hit\n");
                System.out.printf("%f%f%f\n", a, b, c);
            }
            else{
                System.out.printf("ball in boundary\n");
            }


            System.out.printf("Ball 1 at t=%.2f seconds: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)%n", rt, X1, Y1, Z1);

            rt += 1;
            t1 += s1;
            // t2 += s2;
            if (rt>10){
                break;
            }
        }

        // Close the scanner
        scanner.close();
    }


}
```

**Expected Behavior:**

I expect the ball to properly reflect off the boundaries and stay within the box.

**Observed Behavior:**

However, the ball is going outside the boundary and changing its position unexpectedly.

**Question:**

Can you please review the collision detection and reflection part of my code and suggest any corrections?
Is there a more effective way to handle ball reflections off the boundaries within a box?
Additional Information:

Java programming language
Using basic line equations for ball movement
Vector reflection formula for collision handling`

Comment: `X1`, `Y1` and `Z1` are never updated.

Comment: Using notepad? your indentation seems broken, its hard to read code like this, consider fixing it.

Comment: The more effective way is to use [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) to keep track of the ball position and convert the current ball position to cartesian coordinates for collision detection and drawing.

Comment: Here's one [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420910/java-in-netbeans-how-to-moving-ball-with-angle/70424904#70424904) with a ball and polar coordinates.

Comment: Here's a very simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55908354/1552534) of a 2D ball bouncing off the sides of a rectangle.  Since you apparently have a `Z` axis, are you trying to do this in full 3D?

Comment: @WJS Yes I'm trying to do this in 3d

Comment: @tgdavies I am updating it I just provided a code snippet. Here you go pasted the full code

Comment: @GrindingForReputation Fixed it is it alright now?

Comment: Why do you negate the constant term of your line equations when the ball reaches a boundary?

Comment: @tgdavies X1 is being updated using this "X1 = x1 + a * t1", also I tried doing x1=X1 when the ball hits the plane before but was getting weird values. X1 is the position of the ball on the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the code here is the fixed code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class BallExample{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get initial positions for ball 1
    System.out.print("Enter ball 1's initial x-coordinate (x): ");
    double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter ball 1's initial y-coordinate (y): ");
    double y1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter ball 1's initial z-coordinate (z): ");
    double z1 = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter ball 1's radius(r): ");
    double r1 = scanner.nextDouble();

    // Get direction vectorfor ball 1
    System.out.print("Enter direction in x-coordinate (a): ");
    double a = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter direction in y-coordinate (b): ");
    double b = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter direction in z-coordinate (c): ");
    double c = scanner.nextDouble();



    // Get speed
    System.out.print("Enter speed for ball 1(units per second): ");
    double s1 = scanner.nextDouble();





    double rt = 0;
    double t1 = 0;
    while(true) {
        double X1 = x1 + a * t1;
        double Y1 = y1 + b * t1;
        double Z1 = z1 + c * t1;


        System.out.printf("Ball 1 at t=%.2f seconds: (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f)%n", rt, X1, Y1, Z1);

        if (X1+r1>=25||X1-r1<=-25){
            a=-a;
            System.out.printf("HIT\n");
            
        }
        
        
        if (Y1+r1>=25||Y1-r1<=-25){
            b=-b;
            System.out.printf("HIT\n");
            
        }
        
        
        if (Z1+r1>=25||Z1-r1<=-25){
            c=-c;
            System.out.printf("HIT\n");
            
        }

        x1=X1;
        y1=Y1;
        z1=Z1;

        t1 = s1;
        rt += 1;
        if(rt>10){
            break;
        }

    // Close the scanner
    scanner.close();
   }
}}
```